# changing item count in list view not updating in preview

Tags: flutter, listview

In `ListView.seperated` there is an `itemCount` I assumed is the count for the amount that will be displayed, however only the white `Container` appears but not the data inside, inside the class I am using here has more than 5 objects but I only need to display 5 at first I had put in 4 for `itemCount` and run the code, now that I put 5 the data from the class is not appearing even though it appeared for the previous 4

[image: illustration]

```dart
Container(
  height: 300,
  child: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
    height: 700.0,
    child: ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 5,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
          Divider(),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        String word = nameData.getcName(index);
        bool isSaved = nameData.getcFav(index);

        return ListTile(
          tileColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), 
          ),
          leading: SizedBox(
            height: 30,
            width: 60,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  isSaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: isSaved ? Colors.red : null,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                  iconSize: 70,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => listviewScreen()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(nameData.getcName(index)),
          trailing: Text(
            nameData.getcDate(index),
          ),
```

Comment: can you check your `nameData` data

Comment: `class NameData {
  List<Name> _nameData = [
    Name("Lee", "WC", "DL", false, "7/11/2022 10:10"),
    Name("Poh", "DA", "AP", false, "21/12/2021 22:16"),
    Name("Cho", "WB", "CG", false, "09/12/2021 01:10"),
    Name("Kim", "BG", "KJ", false, "12/07/2021 00:00"),
    Name("Lee", "DA", "DL", true, "23/05/2021 10:10"),
    Name("Poh", "WC", "AP", false, "7/11/2022 10:10"),
    Name("Cho", "DA", "CG", true, "7/11/2022 10:10"),
    Name("Kim", "BG", "KJ", false, "7/11/2022 10:10"),
  ];
}`

This is the list I have in nameData

Comment: seems ok to me. Can you include your `getcName` and others method.Also a `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app may also work fine.